# Is there a counterpart of "sufficient"/"enough" meaning "not more than the needed maximum"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, antonyms

I understand the meaning of the word *sufficient* like defined in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sufficient):

> *sufficient* = enough to meet the needs of a situation or a proposed end

So mathematically said:

> *not less than* the needed *minimum*

Is there an "upside-down counterpart"?

> *not more than* the needed *maximum*

It should be of the same style as *sufficient* or *enough*, expressing the same concept (being within limits and not being under the maximum).

Let's have an example of a chemical reaction. In order the reaction can start, you need *at least* 5% concentration of a given substance. So if the concentration is 6%, we say that the concentration is *sufficient*. (Also suggesting that *no more concentration increasing is needed*.)

[image]

However, what if the requirement is that in order the reaction can start, the concentration of the given substance should be *at most* 95%. So if we have 94%, the concentration is ...? *Sufficient* here sounds funny...

Analogically, it should also bear the notion of *no more concentration decreasing is needed*.

[image]

**I am searching for a single word in the same common style as *enough* of *sufficient***, not for a mathematical expression.

*N.B.: I do not mean the same as in the related question [Can "sufficient" be used in a negative sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/63712/73094)*

Comment: why can't you just use the phrase "not too much"? (or in this particular case, "not too high.") Or alternatively, you could perhaps say "sufficiently low" or "low enough."  I don't see why you need a single word.

Comment: @sumelic: yes, I can - but I was wondering if "sufficient"/"enough" has a single-word counterpart.

Comment: in this example does 'at most' mean if concentration less than 95% or less than or equal to 95%?

Comment: Good question, but why on earth are you presenting it as a single word request? It may well happen that there is a good way to express this, but not with one word. E.g., one might say "within limits" or "not over the top".

Comment: @niallhaslam: "at most" always means "less than or equal to."

Comment: Surely "less than" is the simplest and clearest phrase here - "This value needs to be *less than* [the threshold]". Not a single word I grant you, but the fewest words to provide the meaning, I contend. If you need a word that means *both* higher than the minimum and also less than the maximum, perhaps your value is 'optimal' or 'in the optimum range'.

Comment: @anemone: what on earth is wrong with searching for a single word? :) If we have "enough" or "sufficient" for the one concept, why shouldn't I search if there is a single-word expression for the other?

Comment: @MarvMills: your expression "less than the threshold" doesn't express the analogous concept as "sufficient" does in the other way.

Comment: @HonzaZidek I did not mean it's wrong. It just possibly clashes with the (much more important, imo) request for the best possible expression.

Comment: @niallhaslam: I think you are missing the point of the question... I am searching for a word from the *common* language, which usually ignores nuances such as *open* or *closed* interval.

Comment: @anemone: well, I can think of many possible ways of expressing the idea. However, I was wondering if we have a *single-word* expression with the same concept as *enough* or *sufficient*, but "upside-down".

Comment: @HonzaZidek Fine. Btw, instead of upside-down, you might want to use "dual".

Comment: "not more than the needed maximum"  is incoherent. A _needed_ maximum means both no more (the maximum) and no less (needed).

Comment: As I had pointed in my answer, sufficient is something within parameters or requirements, whether they are upper conditions, lower conditions or a range or conditions to meet. If every necesary condition is met, then it is sufficient. If, however you don't feel at home with "enough" or "sufficient", why don't you just use "acceptable", "adequate", "satisfactory" or "tolerable" to describe what is "not excessive" or (as I had pointed out before), "within limits"?

Comment: @SamuelVimes: because none of your proposals is sufficient? :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek your logic is faulty - Sufficient comes from 'suffice' - in other words "does the value suffice in meeting your needs?" - Your needs are that the value must fall within an upper and lower boundary. A value within those values does suffice as it meets your conditions- it is therefore 'sufficient'.

Comment: @MarvMills exactly!, that is what I am trying to explain

Comment: @MarvMills: An easy test of your theory is that. Suppose the second chemical reaction from my example requiring at most 95% concentration. What would you do, if you had 96% concentration and were told that it is not sufficient? Would you even come up with the idea of *decreasing* it???

Comment: I would ask "in what way is this sample not sufficient for the needs of this reaction?".

Comment: I don't think it would be the natural reaction. I state that without being notified otherwise, the common action after telling that the amount is not sufficient is *increasing* the amount. It might not reflect the etymology of *sufficient* but I believe it's the common way of using that word.

Comment: Then according to your model you would not be told "It is not sufficient" you would be told "It is too concentrated".

Comment: Great! So what would be the *positive* sentence meaning "it is concentrated within limits, not more than allowed", using one word with analogous meaning as *sufficient* (so also bearing the meaning of "no more decreasing is needed")? Maybe there is *not* such a word...

Comment: It is sufficiently concentrated, or it has the sufficient concentration...

Comment: It is sufficiently concentrated, so I do not need to increase the concentration...

Comment: It is sufficiently concentrated, so I do not need to change the concentration.

Comment: "Sufficiently low" is exactly right!

Comment: To me, "sufficient" indicates that it meets or exceeds requirements/pre-requisites/expectations (i.e. a >= relationship). I feel that the asker is looking for a single word describing an "up to but not exceeding" relationship (i.e. a <= relationship). With this in mind, I agree with a commenter above that the phrase `not more than the needed maximum` would be better replaced with `not more than the permitted maximum`.

Comment: Phrases such as "sufficiently low" (suggested above by @ThePopMachine) and "within permitted tolerances" do not meet the single-word criteria but do indicate an upper bound (unlike most current answers whose words anchor on the lower bound).

Comment: Tangential: I agree with the previous complaint than "needed maximum" is very confusing.  I had to read the question multiple times before I understood what it is asking, perhaps because "needed" has the same "or more" connotation that "sufficient" does, at least for me.  It would have made a lot more sense to me to read "necessary maximum," or to even leave out the modifier completely--just "maximum" would have sufficed.

Comment: @kwah: Well, *sufficiently low* does not meet the single-word criterion, but bears exactly the full *meaning* of what I am searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think “sufficient” covers the whole range between insufficiently low (too low) and insufficiently high (too high), but I do agree that “sufficient” (and especially “enough”) can imply that the lower end of that range has been (just barely?) reached.

Just as, imo, “sufficient” covers the whole acceptable/sufficient range (with a bias towards the low end), so does “[tolerable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/tolerable)” cover the whole acceptable/tolerable range, but perhaps with the bias towards the high end that you are seeking.

“Tolerable”: adjective/ bearable, endurable, supportable, **acceptable**. (Oxford Dictionnaires)

Step 1: **Insufficiently low**/intolerably low (too low) = **insufficient**/intolerable/unacceptable);

Step 2: **Sufficiently high**/tolerably low (high enough/not too low) = **sufficient**/tolerable/acceptable;

Step 3: **Tolerably high**/sufficiently low (not too high/low enough) = **tolerable**/sufficient/acceptable;

Step 4: **Intolerably high**/insufficiently high (too high) = **intolerable**/insufficient/unacceptable.

The above steps are trying to show that “insufficient, sufficient, tolerable, and intolerable” can be used at both ends of the range of acceptability, but please note that the **bolded** words in each step are, in my opinion, ‘best suited for’/most often associated with that step.

Both “insufficiently” and “intolerably” use “low” in Step 1 and “high” in Step 4 to convey the meaning of those two Steps, which could mean that the bias towards either the low end (sufficient) or the high end (tolerable) that I perceive in these two words disappears when discussing unacceptable levels below and above the acceptable range.

Within the range of acceptability, however, “high” and “low” must be flipped to make sense of “tolerable” and “sufficient” as they are used in Steps 2 and 3, which, imo, supports the bias that I perceive and perhaps supports “tolerable” as the best one-word answer to your question.

Comment: It's true that SamuelVimes came with *tolerable* before you, but as I do not agree with the rest of his answer (namely the claimed "symmetry" of *sufficient* towards both ends), I tend to accept your answer *tolerable* as sufficient :) (unless someone comes with something even better)

Comment: Thanks, but my answer came long after @Samuel 's (I missed his mention of 'tolerable' until after posting mine, but instead of deleting mine I chose to leave it and upvote his) and I also agree with Samuel that 'sufficient'  covers both ends (with a bias towards the lower end), so please don't accept mine over his for that reason alone, or for any reason, for that matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Quite simply "not in excess".

Since [*excess*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/excess) means:

> An amount of something that is more than necessary, permitted, or desirable:

and *in excess* means:

> Exceeding the proper amount or degree

(from ODO)

So if something is in excess then it is more than sufficient.

Comment: An amount which is "barely sufficient" can also be described as "not in excess". This isn't specific enough for the asker's needs.

Comment: @taimu While this is literally true, my experience is that it is not usually used in that manner. If I am given only one bound, I attempt to get rather close to that bound. The same way, if I were told 5% is enough, I would not go for 95%.

Answer (score 6):

This can also be referred to as an ***appropriate***. It is a general word, not necessarily meaning that levels are in the desired range, but given the context, I think it is clear. ***suitable*** might serve well as well.

> **appropriate**
>
> *adjective*
>
> (ə-prō′prē-ĭt)
>
> **Suitable for a particular** person, **condition**, occasion, or place; fitting.

*Source: [TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appropriate)*

Comment: While this doesn't precisely specify the bounds the question asked for, I think it is likely the best we can get with a single word answer.  Since the asker emphasized the single word requirement, +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

By the same definition you have given:

> sufficient = enough to meet the needs of a situation or a proposed end

But in my opinion that does not translate to:

> not less than the needed minimum

But rather to:

> not less than the needed minimum AND no more than the allowed maximum

As in your case, exceeding such limit doesn't allow you to meet the needs or requirements of your situation. So I would still say that 94% concentration is ***sufficient***. However, if you prefer, you could say that the concentration is within parameters o within limits. Also, perhaps you can say that it is an ***acceptable***, ***tolerable*** or ***adequate*** concentration, to imply that it is within limits.

Comment: Well, I was asking for a single word :)

Comment: The sentence "The 94% concentration is sufficient to start the reaction" is very misleading in the case where the 96% concentration is too much and the reaction will not start.

Comment: Agreed - if the word were negated, and I was told that the 96% concentration was "insufficient", I would increase the concentration.

Comment: @Matt & Honza: But that is because your initial assumption is incorrect. Sufficient does not actually mean "enought" but rather, "satisfactory" or "adequate". To put it differently: if something is sufficient it is because it adquately fullfills the requirements. Another thing is that, as the requierements we normally find in our lives have a lower bound rather than an upper one, we tend to associate a minimum condition with a sufficient one.

Comment: @SamuelVimes: "sufficient," "satisfactory," "adequate" all seem to be synonyms of "enough." I get what you're saying, but I agree with Honza Zidek that it doesn't sound right to use "sufficient" to mean "not too much" in this kind of context.

Comment: @sumelic yes, I also get what you are saying, but that is why I offered alternatives like "within parameters". "Not in excess" would also work nicely to imply "don't put too much" or, as you say, simply: "not too much".

Comment: Yeah; "within parameters" is good. It's too bad it's not a single word, and the OP truly wants "one" word. (not sarcasm)

Comment: @sumelic I agree with you. What do you think about 'tolerable' or 'acceptable' as a kind of one-word replacement for 'within parameters'?

Comment: @SamuelVimes: With *tolerable* or *acceptable* I miss the implicit message which I feel *sufficient* or *enough* bears, i.e. "no need to (further) decrease the amount".

Comment: @HonzaZidek Ok, what about "adequate" or "satisfactory"?

Comment: @SamuelVimes: Kind of, but I still do not have the yes-that's-it feeling...

Comment: @SamuelVimes: considering it again, maybe really *tolerable* is the best of all the solutions proposed so far. But still I don't agree with you that *sufficient* (or even *enough*) in **common language** carries the "no more than the allowed maximum" meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You could say the 94% concentration is ***effective***. However, this doesn't really address whether it's possible to have too much, or too little, or both. It won't lead to any incorrect interpretations, though.

Comment: Although you really could say *that*, it doesn't answer my question and maybe should rather be a comment (however valuable and relevant) :)

Answer (score 2):

The closest word I can think of off the top of my head is **requisite**, which in my mind implies an exactness of quantity (as opposed to **enough**/**sufficient** or **more than enough**/**plentiful**). That said, the literal definition of **requisite** in the dictionary includes an allusion to the word **necessary**, thereby leaning towards "above the minimum" and not necessarily answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I miss my guess, you're looking for a word from the 'common' language (using as models 'sufficient' and 'enough') that means 'at least X but no more than Y'.

That word is 'competent':

> **competent**
>
> *adjective*
>
> ...
>
> 2. Being what is needed without being in excess

(competent. (n.d.) The American Heritage Roget’s Thesaurus. (2014). Retrieved September 12 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/competent).

So, paraphrasing the the example you give,

> concentrations from 5% to 95% are competent to produce the reaction

and

> a concentration of 6% is competent to produce the reaction

as well as

> a concentration of 94% is competent to produce the reaction

In each case the intended meaning of 'enough but no more than enough' is expressed by 'competent'.

Comment: So a solution of 94% is competent? That wording doesn't seem to work for me. But, "competent" may work in other contexts.

Comment: @sumelic, why doesn't it work for you? I edited hard science manuscripts for years, and that use of 'competent' is acceptable (would be understood), although the more usual approach would be to spell out the range.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your answer all the way before commenting. It looks like this is a fine word to use. It sounds odd to me. But this is probably just because I have never written or edited a science manuscript.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention mathematics, it is worth mentioning that *sufficient* usually is contrasted with *necessary*. A simple example: Let A be the statement

> The function *f* is continuous,

and B the statement

> The function *f* is differentiable.

Then B implies A, i e B is the stronger property of *f*. This can be expressed as:

> B is sufficient for A.

Another way to say this is:

> A is necessary for B.

Comment: In my example the sentence "The 94% concentration is *necessary* to start the reaction" would have quite a different meaning be default, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is maximal. As in the maximal concentration of the substance for the reaction is 94%.

> of or constituting a maximum; as great or as large as possible.

Comment: But here, the maximal concentration of the substance for the reaction is actually 95%.

Comment: Also, even if you disagree or aren't sure about that, since the definition is only "not more than the maximum," whatever term used has to also apply to 93%, 92%, 91% and so on, which are clearly not the maximum concentration of the substance for the reaction. "Maximum" specifies a single point; the OP is looking for a word that refers to a range of values.

Comment: Agree - I think it would be clearer if the question used a number not so close to the limit in order to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

How about "in range". It states not to exceed the maximum (nor the minimum, if any). It doesn't imply being near the maximum though, which you seem to be searching for.

"The 94% concentration is in (the) range to start the reaction"

Comment: I completely miss the implicit message which I feel *sufficient* or *enough* bears towards the low end, but here towards the high end, i.e. "no need to (further) decrease the amount".

Answer (score 1):

One word that comes up somewhat regularly in scientific contexts is **parsimonious**:

> 1: exhibiting or marked by parsimony; especially :  frugal to the point of stinginess
>
> 2:  sparing, restrained

**parsimony**:

> a :  the quality of being careful with money or resources :  thrift
>
> b :  the quality or state of being stingy
>
> 2:  economy in the use of means to an end; especially :  economy of explanation in conformity with Occam's razor

(from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parsimonious))

A parsimonious theory is one which doesn't involve any extraneous features. A [parsimonious evolutionary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_parsimony_(phylogenetics)) is one which minimizes the number of evolutionary "events" (mutations) which occurred.

So a "parsimonious concentration of reactant" would be interpreted as being the bare minimum needed to show the desired effect, with none extra or "wasted".

(All that said, I will admit I've never heard "parsimonious" used to describe compound concentrations, although I can't ever recall a situation where such a single word phrasing would have been needed.)

Comment: So parsimonious means enough, sufficient...

Comment: Yes, parsimonious implies having enough, but without having much more than the minimum required.

Comment: I don't think *parsimonious* really implies *sufficient* to any problematic degree, at least in general language use. It's a common generalisation of *thrifty* (virtue) and *avaricious* (vice). A connotation of *sufficient* is unavoidable just like it's unavoidable that *sufficient* connotes *parsimonious*: "The water in your bathtub is sufficient. (In fact, I nearly drowned when opening the bathroom door.)" - "The water in your bathtub is parsimonious. (In fact, I removed the plug hours ago. I just didn't get around to drying it up.)" Both are misleading in the same way.

Comment: The problem with *parsimonious* is not so much in the degrees it describes as in the kind of scales it is usually applied to. It still has a very strong connotation of being about money. But as a metaphor it seems to be a very good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i strongly believe that there is something very, very, very wrong with the "needed maximum" wording in the first place.

Different story if you said: the maximum allowed, which means that if you pour more, things will go wrong.

If you persist in such ill wordings, i  believe you'll end up entangled in the quest for a language chimera that will haunt you for life.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, but you do never address the original question. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: This is a valid point but it should be a comment (yes, I know you can't).

Answer (score 0):

When discussing the amount of food (or alcohol) that I’ve just consumed/am consuming, I often talk in terms of the progression from 1) “too little/not enough,” to 2) “enough,” to 3) “**full**,” and finally to 4) “too much,” where “full” might fit somewhere in your nice graphs.

However, although “[full](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/full)” (or the fancier “[saturated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/saturated)" in non-chemical contexts) does convey that no more **increasing** is possible, permitted, or needed; it admittedly doesn’t bear the notion you're after that “no more **decreasing** is needed.”   (The Free Dictionary)

Comment: "saturated" seems similar, but unfortunately in a chemical context like the one in the original post it has a specific and distinct meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you want a **moderate** amount:

> Kept or keeping within reasonable or proper limits; not extreme, excessive, or intense

(From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moderate))

You could also say that you want **just enough** of something (though this is a phrase rather than a single word).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the "needed maximum" you refer to is so needed because it describes an arbitrary limit less than the "possible maximum". For example, when you're filling your car's gas tank, the "needed maximum" gas to dispense is equal to the tank's *capacity*, while the "possible maximum" gas to dispense is limited by how much fuel the station has in storage. If you fill your gas tank to the "needed maximum", you can say you've filled it *to capacity*, and if you continue to dispense gas beyond that point, you can say you've *overfilled* the tank.

Therefore, a term that satisfies your requirements is *capacity*. You could also use *limit* (e.g. "filled *to its limits*"), extent (e.g. "prosecuted *to the extent* of the law"), and so on in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

In object relations theory, one writes of and holds in high esteem the "good enough" mother, or the "ordinary devoted mother," meaning a mother who is adequate to the task of mothering, not perfect or, pejoratively, perfectionistic. Competent and adequate work well as synonyms; the antonym would be inadequate.